# Laravel : Undefined offset:3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get an error

> Undefined offset: 3

What i want is in edit if $`view_360` and $`iframe_title` empty to find that iframe and delete it . Any suggestion how can i do that?

```
for ($i=0; $i <= count($view_360); $i++) {

      if(!empty($view_360[$i])){
        if($request->view360_id[$i] == "undefined"){
          $view_360_iframe = new View360();
        }
        else {
         $view_360_iframe = View360::findOrFail($request->view360_id[$i]);
        }
        $view_360_iframe->property_id = $property->id;
        $view_360_iframe->title = $iframe_title[$i];
        $view_360_iframe->iframe = $view_360[$i];
        $view_360_iframe->save();

      }
      if(empty($view_360[$i]) && empty($iframe_title[$i])){
          $view_360_iframe = View360::findOrFail($request->view360_id[$i]);
          $view_360_iframe->delete();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need `$i < count($view_360)` instead `$i <= count($view_360)`. So you have $view_360[0], $view_360[1] and $view_360[2], but you haven't $view_360[3].